# Are there any reasons not to use ggplot() + aes() + geom_() syntax?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a fairly experienced `ggplot2` user and teach it to university students. However, I only just came across an example that uses the following syntax:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + aes(cyl) + geom_histogram()
```

This fits a lot better into the logic of adding up layers than specifying `aes` inside `ggplot()` or the `geom_` ... but it does not seem to be documented anywhere in the ggplot2 help. Therefore, I am wondering whether there are any reasons why this syntax is limited / should not be used? (Obviously, I see that it needs to be specified in the geom if it is meant to differ between geoms ...)

Comment: I occasionally see this too, but prefer the documented approach specified inside `ggplot()` or a `geom_` as it forces the default to be specified early rather than say accidentally doing something like this `ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(cyl)) + aes(mpg)`.

Comment: One reason might be that each `geom` can own separate or additional `aes`thetics to those defined at top level (e.g. within the `ggplot`) call. Thus, presenting a single top-level `aes` call might make it harder for students to discover the "layerability" of aesthetics. my 2 cents ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is verging on an opinion-based question, but I think it is on-topic, since it helps to clarify the syntax and structure of ggplot calls.

In a sense you have already answered the question yourself:

> it does not seem to be documented anywhere in the ggplot2 help

This, and the near absence of examples in online tutorials, blogs and SO answers is a good enough reason not to use `aes` this way (or at least not to teach people to use it this way). It could lead to confusion and frustration on the part of new users.

> This fits a lot better into the logic of adding up layers

This is *sort of* true, but could be a bit misleading. What it actually does is to specify the *default* aesthetic mapping, that subsequent layers will inherit from the `ggplot` object itself. It should be considered a core *part* of the base plot, along with the default data object, and therefore "belongs" in the initial `ggplot` call, rather than something that is being added or layered on to the plot. If you create a default `ggplot` object without data and mapping, the slots are still there, but contain waivers rather than being `NULL` :

```r
p <- ggplot()

p$mapping
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> <empty>

p$data
#> list()
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "waiver"
```

Note that unlike the scales and co-ordinate objects, for which you might argue that the same is also true, there can be no defaults for data and aesthetic mappings.

Does this mean you should *never* use this syntax? No, but it should be considered an advanced trick for folks who are well versed in ggplot. The most frequent use case I find for it is in changing the mapping of ggplots that are created in extension packages, such as `ggsurvplot` or `ggraph`, where the plotting functions use wrappers around `ggplot`. It can also be used to quickly create multiple plots with the same themes and colour scales:

```r
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  theme_light()

library(patchwork)

p + (p + aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length))
```

[image]

So the bottom line is that you can use this if you want, but best avoid teaching it to beginners

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

I cannot see any strong reasons why not to use this pattern, but other patterns are recommended in the documentation, without elaboration.

#### What does `+ aes()` do?

A ggplot has two types of aesthetics:

- the default one (typically supplied inside `ggplot()`), and
- `geom_*()` specific aesthetics

If `inherit.aes = TRUE` is set inside the geoms, then these two types of aesthetics are combined in the final plot. If the default aesthetic is not set, then the `geom_*` specific aesthetics must be set.

Using `ggplot(df) + aes(x, y)` changes the **default** aesthetic.

This is documented in `?"+.gg"`:

> An aes() object replaces the default aesthetics.

#### Are there any reasons not to use it?

I cannot see any strong reasons not to. However, in the documentation of `?ggplot` it is stated that:

> There are three common ways to invoke ggplot():
>
> - ggplot(df, aes(x, y, other aesthetics))
> - ggplot(df)
> - ggplot()
>
> The first method is recommended if all layers use the same data and the same set of aesthetics.

As far as I can see, the typical use case for `+ aes()` is when all layers use the same aesthetics. So the documentation recommend the usual pattern `ggplot(df, aes(x, y, other aesthetics))`, but I cannot find an elaboration of why.

Further: even though the plots look identical, the objects returned by `ggplot(df, aes()` and `ggplot(df) + aes()` are not identical, so there might be some edge cases where one pattern would lead to errors or a different plot.

You can see the many small differences with this code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + geom_point()
b <- ggplot(mtcars) + aes(hp, mpg) + geom_point()

waldo::compare(a, b, x_arg = "a", y_arg = "b")
```